# How to itextsharp PDF open in new tab in chrome using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I m using this code but its not working . Pdf File open in same page 
this is my code

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.Charset = string.Empty;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.Public);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "inline; filename=ChallanReceive.pdf");
        Response.OutputStream.Write(PDFData.GetBuffer(), 0, PDFData.GetBuffer().Length);

        Response.OutputStream.Flush();
        Response.OutputStream.Close();
        Response.End();
```

Comment: You cannot decide what will happen with a document on the client side...

Answer (score 0):

Just use a hyperlink to the pdf file and set the target to "_blank."

```
<a href="YourURL" target="_blank">
```

This will solve you the problem.